# Another recurrence... $T(n)=\sqrt{2n} \cdot T(\sqrt{2n}) + \sqrt{n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I'm trying to solve the following recurrence :
$$T(n)=\sqrt{2n}\cdot T(\sqrt{2n}) + \sqrt{n}$$

I've tried substituting $n$ for some other variables to transform the above to something easier without luck. Then I used a recursion tree on $n$ and I got that the sum at each level $m$ is: $$2\sqrt{2}\cdot \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{3/2^{m}},$$ and the term $$T \left(2 \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{3/2^{m-1}} \right).$$   I don't know how to calculate the tree's depth; well I don't even know if I doing this correctly or if I should find another way. Help  is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you set $S(n)=\frac{T(n)}{n}$ and divide your recurrence by $n$, you get $S(n)=\sqrt{2}S(\sqrt{2n})+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest proceeding as follows.  Set $$
m=log_2(n)-1
$$ so that $$
n=2^{m+1}
$$ and $$
\sqrt{2n}=2^{\frac{m}{2}+1}
$$
Then defining $S(m)=\frac{T(2^{m+1})}{2^{m+1}}$ produces$$
\begin{align*}
S(m) & =\frac{T(n)}{n} = 2\frac{T(\sqrt{2n})}{\sqrt{2n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\\
& = 2S\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2^\frac{m+1}{2}}
\end{align*}
$$which has the form of the [the master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. Nice transformation!